# RewriteRule exception for static page outside WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm searching Google since at least 20 minutes and I can't believe it's that hard to find...

It should be pretty easy but I can't figure it out...

*THE PROBLEM:*

I want to put a HTML file at the same level of my Wordpress, but don't want the RewriteRules to "trap" this page and think it's a redirect...

*THE HTACCESS:*

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# >> here << this next line is my TEST....
RewriteRule ^test\.htm$ test.htm [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Of course, a page called "test.htm" is uploaded on the server.

As stated, the line where I put my test doesn't work.  It shows the WordPress homepage, instead of my "test.htm" page I uploaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try this one:

```
RewriteRule ^test\.htm$ - [PT,L]
```

It passes through (PT) the request and does not apply any further rules (L).